According to the Catholic Church, is the priest in persona Christi during the mass?
I know that the Catholic Church teaches during confession the priest acts "in persona Christi" (in the person of Christ). Since the mass is meant to be a re-presentation of Christ's sacrifice on the cross, and this occurs in the re-enactment of the Last Supper, does the priest act in persona Christi? Are there only certain points when this is the case (for instance is he not during the Homily)?

Yes, the priest acts in persona Christi at Mass. The Catechism says this in paragraph 1548.

In the ecclesial service of the ordained minister, it is Christ himself who is present to his Church as Head of his Body, Shepherd of his flock, high priest of the redemptive sacrifice, Teacher of Truth. This is what the Church means by saying that the priest, by virtue of the sacrament of Holy Orders, acts in persona Christi Capitis:
It is the same priest, Christ Jesus, whose sacred person his minister truly represents. Now the minister, by reason of the sacerdotal consecration which he has received, is truly made like to the high priest and possesses the authority to act in the power and place of the person of Christ himself (virtute ac persona ipsius Christi).
Christ is the source of all priesthood: the priest of the old law was a figure of Christ, and the priest of the new law acts in the person of Christ.

And paragraph 1550

This presence of Christ in the minister is not to be understood as if the latter were preserved from all human weaknesses, the spirit of domination, error, even sin. The power of the Holy Spirit does not guarantee all acts of ministers in the same way. While this guarantee extends to the sacraments, so that even the minister's sin cannot impede the fruit of grace, in many other acts the minister leaves human traces that are not always signs of fidelity to the Gospel and consequently can harm the apostolic fruitfulness of the Church.

So the priest is only acting in persona Christi when he is celebrating the Sacraments. Regarding the celebration of the Mass, I would think this would apply only to the Words of Consecration and the distribution of the Blessed Sacrament, since those are the essential components of the Sacrament in question.
